# How do I fix my StackOverflow Error for my Optional?

Tags: java, option-type, point, optional-parameters, optional-arguments

I am working on an assignment for class, and I just can't seem to figure out what is causing this StackOverflow Error.

**Some Background:**

The point of this specific method is to return an Optional  that is moving in a straight line using the MoveStrategy interface. The parameters *dx* and *dy* act as our "offsets" and we have to add them to our BlobView's current location.

```
public class StraightLineMovement implements MoveStrategy
{

  private final int dx;
  private final int dy;

  /**
   * Construct an instance which will, on each call to move, move the blob by the given offsets.
   *
   * @param dx the distance the Blob should move along the x axis
   * @param dy the distance the Blob should move along the y axis
   */
  public StraightLineMovement(int dx, int dy) 
  {
      this.dx = dx;
      this.dy = dy;
  }

  @Override
  public Optional<Point> move(BlobView bv) 
  {
        Point bvLocation = bv.getLocation();
        double bvRadius = bv.getRadius();
        
        int bv_X = bvLocation.x + dx;
        int bv_Y = bvLocation.y + dy;
        
        Point newLocation = new SimplePoint (bv_X, bv_Y);
        
        StraightLineMovement strategy = new StraightLineMovement (dx, dy);
        
        
        BlobView newView = new BlobView (newLocation, bvRadius);
        System.out.println ("Point: (" + newLocation.x + ", " + newLocation.y + ")");
        
        Optional <Point> movement = strategy.move(newView);
       
        return movement;
        //return movement.map(point -> point.moveTo(new_X, new_Y));
  }
}
```

It keeps giving me that error when I actually *make* the optional.

Here is the MoveStrategy Interface:

```
import java.util.Optional;

public interface MoveStrategy 
{

    public Optional<Point> move(BlobView bv);
}
```

I want to note that the results I am getting from the print statement *are* correct (as in, they are moving correctly), but I just cannot figure out how to fix this. At first, I thought it was my return statement (and it still could be), but I have tried to use .map, .filter, ect. to try and fix it, but I couldn't figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You are creating a Object with the same values each time `StraightLineMovement strategy = new StraightLineMovement (dx, dy);`

Comment: What do you want `move` to actually return? Let's say I have a blob view `bv` at (0, 0), and I have a straight line move strategy `strat` with dx=100 and dy=0, and I call `strat.move(bv)`. What _value_ would you expect that to return? An empty optional? A `Point` (if so what are the coordinates)? And most importantly, _why?_

Comment: `StraightLineMovement#move` creates a `new` `StraightLineMovement strategy` and then calls `move` on it.

Comment: @ScaryWombat, Okay, that makes sense. I am not really sure what to put in the assignment though. Like, StraightLineMovement strategy = /*....*/?

Comment: @Sweeper, I want move to return an Optional <Point>. The idea is for the dx and dy (which stay the same) variables to constantly be added to the current location of the BlobView (it is supposed to mimic going in a straight line).

Comment: That does not answer my question. What _value_ do you want `move` to return in the situation I described? If you want the BlobView to keep moving, when do you want it to stop? I suggest that you explain very clearly what it is that you want to achieve, to avoid being an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).